# MS Word: "Update all fields" seems to be corrupting fields in text boxes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-formatting, field-codes

I'm afraid I'm on the verge of a catastrophe. I have a very large Microsoft Word document (nearly 500 pages), and I'm finding that every time I "update all fields" by the Ctrl-A, F9 method, a large number of my fields are corrupted -- specifically, AutoNumber'd captions in text boxes. This makes me afraid to "update all fields" at all, even though I need my internal references to be coherent.[image: An example of a corrupted text box.]

This is an example of a corrupted text box. The caption text is repeated once or twice, possibly autoincremented, possibly keeping the same number (but still messing up the numbering of the next entry). This majorly messes up the numbering of the whole document. Sometimes, text from entirely different text boxes and entirely different sequences gets inserted into a text box. The thing is, because this text is dumped into text boxes, I can't always tell that it is there, if the boxes are collapsed; sometimes the text hides in the word wrap, and I don't find it until I manually expand the text box. So I can't be sure *exactly* when this occurred, if it happened the last time I Ctrl-A, F9'ed, or if it has been hiding for a while. But in some cases, I can tell that it definitely just occurred, as text boxes I only recently added become corrupt. This does not occur with caption entries that are not enclosed in text boxes.

If I manually remove the corrupt text and manually update each field, things seem to work properly. But as you can imagine, hunting for corrupt text and manually updating hundreds of fields is quite tedious, and I want to stop this from happening in the future if at all possible. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening and what I can do about it?

A few notes:

- I'm editing this document across several different computers, three of them running Windows 10 and one running Mac OS X Monterey. All of these systems have Office 365 installed, the Windows systems having Word Version 2204 (Build 15128.20178) and the Mac having Word 16.60 (22041000).
- I do my best to avoid having the document open on more than one computer at once (but occasionally I'll forget to close it on one).
- The document has no macros, just a whole lot of pages.

---

Edit:
Here is a [link to a small excerpt](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AjxSHIA3uO-mpz5YOnqMQ0LiDHIw?e=BftrTT). Note the first of the two map captions (the left one) has repeated/corrupt text if you expand it. This is just a small example. I did the Ctrl-A, F9 think on my more reliable Windows machine and it still created problems.

Comment: **Even though they have the same name and use the same data files, Word programs on different platforms are not the same program.** *Can you clip out a couple of the ones that cause problems in a separate document and post a view link to that document here?* https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: To the extent you can insert your images inline with text and have the same with the captions, you will have a hardier document.

Comment: I've never observed the problem using Word for Mac. I use that on the document only rarely and usually not for very long. I've actually only observed the problem on *one* of the Windows machines.

Alas, inline images and captions don't seem to have the layout flexibility that I need.

Comment: The problem results in an "End tag does not match" error message which is confounding. It is a type of document corruption that has only been observed, AFAIK, in documents with floating images. It may well be that it only occurs on Windows machines. I do not know. I have not experienced this myself and am speaking from experience advising on the Microsoft Answers forum. -- still could use the excerpt to assist

Comment: That diagnosis would be consistent with how this behaves and what I've observed from dissecting the file and looking at the raw XML. It seems to re-absorb all the caption data from the current textbox caption and the NEXT textbox caption (even if it is in a different sequence), and dump that back into the textbox. I'll post an excerpt soon. Any ideas from the MS forum on what to do about it?

Comment: Here is a link to a small excerpt. Note the first of the two map captions (the left one) has repeated/corrupt text if you expand it. https://1drv.ms/w/s!AjxSHIA3uO-mpz5YOnqMQ0LiDHIw?e=BftrTT
This is just a small example. I did the Ctrl-A, F9 think on my more reliable Windows machine and it still created problems. I suppose textboxes and fields are just broken? Wish I'd known that before I made so many of them.
Would there have been any other way to create this layout without floating images or text boxes?

Comment: Initially, the only problem I see is that there is a caption for a map that is not showing combined. Updating fields does nothing. Need a sample pre-corruption. You may want to cross-post this on the Word Answers forum. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: The problem is that I never know when or where the corruption will occur. I will just be careful, avoid Ctrl-A, F9 on the entire document, and only update a smaller group of fields at a time. That seems to be getting the job done. Thanks for your help.